# Daily evm performance chart for projects

Tags: apex, dashboard, visualforce, charts

In need a daily evm performance chart like the picture below.It needs to begin from the beginning of the project and it needs to be line chart just like this.Is there any possibility to create it without apex visual force page?Thanks in advance.

[image: Evm performance]

Comment: You have some custom objects that represent this data? Or are you trying to infer it in some way from the content of your org?

Comment: @KeithC        I have custom object represent this data.

Comment: Then the first thing to try is to build a report and connect that up to a graphical dashboard component. Google to find various articles on this e.g. http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewQuickStarts?id=000113375&language=en_US. How easy or hard that will be depends what your custom object represents. If you can't make that work, a small Apex controller and a page holding an apex:chart wouldn't be too hard to create.